# Primefaces remoteCommand not invoke oncomplete JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have problem with remoteCommand. This component never invoke oncomplete and working only one time. Where I made mistake?

```
<p:remoteCommand name="showClientEditPopup" action="#{clientController.setCurrentClient}" oncomplete="alert('OnComplete');">
    </p:remoteCommand>
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was problem with library noty.js (I'm migrating app from RichFaces to PrimeFaces). Solution was simple - migrate noty.js to newer version.